# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n^2}{5n^2+1}=\frac25$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2n^2}{5n^2+1}=\dfrac{2}{5}$

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \ \ :\exists N(\epsilon)\in \mathbb{N}  \ \ \text{such that} \ \  \forall n >N(\epsilon)  \ \ \text{we have} |\dfrac{-2}{25n^2+5}|<\epsilon$$
$$ |\dfrac{-2}{25n^2+5}|<\epsilon \\  |\dfrac{2}{25n^2+5}|<\epsilon \\  \dfrac{5(n^2+1)}{2}<\epsilon \\ {5(n^2+1)}<2\epsilon \\ {n}>\sqrt{\dfrac{2\epsilon -5}{25}}$$

What do I do?

Comment: follow this : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/201499?rq=1 or this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943182/prove-lim-n-to-infty-frac2nn2-2?rq=1

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \ \ :\exists n_0\in \mathbb{N}  \ \ \text{such that} \ \  \forall n >n_0 \quad \left|\dfrac{2n^2}{5n^2+1}-\dfrac{2}{5}\right|<\epsilon$$

$$\left|\dfrac{-2}{25n^2+5}\right|<\epsilon\iff \dfrac{2}{25n^2+5}<\epsilon\iff 25n^2+5>\frac{2}{\epsilon}\iff25n^2> \frac{2}{\epsilon}-5\iff n^2>\frac{2}{25\epsilon}-\frac15\implies n> \sqrt{\frac{2}{25\epsilon}-\frac15}$$

Comment: but I want to use the definition...

Comment: @Fricul38 I've updated with the derivation

Comment: There is a problem in gimusi's answer . That is, for $\varepsilon>\frac{2}{5}$ the expression under radical is neg.

Comment: @M.R.Yegan the problem is solved keeping $\varepsilon<\frac{2}{5}$

Comment: In the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of" limit" just $\varepsilon>0$

Comment: we can also give an upper bound to $\epsilon$, it’s really a matter of burocracy and not math!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon >0$

$|\dfrac{-2}{25n^2+5}|<\varepsilon\iff \dfrac{2}{25n^2+5}<\varepsilon$

$\dfrac{2}{25n^2+5}<\dfrac{2}{25n^2}<\varepsilon$ so $n^2>\dfrac{2}{25\varepsilon}\iff n>\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{5\sqrt{\varepsilon}}$

Then $N(\varepsilon)=\bigg\lfloor\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{5\sqrt{\varepsilon}}\bigg\rfloor+1$

Comment: what is $E\bigg[\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{5\sqrt{\varepsilon}}\bigg]+1$

Comment: that is the floor function

Comment: I changed it with the usual notation

Answer (score 1):

If you want an $\epsilon,\delta$ proof of the limit then given an $\epsilon>0$ you must find an $N>0$ such that if $n>N$ then

$$ \left\vert \frac{2n^2}{5n^2+1}-\frac{2}{5}\right\vert<\epsilon $$

That is,

$$ \frac{2}{25n^2+5}<\epsilon $$

You may replace the expression on the left by a larger expression to simplify the exercise, such as for example

$$\frac{2}{25n^2+5}<\frac{2}{25n^2}<\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Then if you can find for which values of $n$ it is true that

$$ \frac{1}{n^2}<\epsilon $$ then it will also be true that

$$ \frac{2}{25n^2+5}<\epsilon $$

So clearly we want $n>N>\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$.

But this analysis is just the prequel to the actual proof.

$$\text{Prove that } \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2n^2}{5n^2+1}=\dfrac{2}{5} $$

Let $\epsilon>0$ and let $N>\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$. Then $\frac{1}{N^2}<\epsilon$. Let $n>N$. Then

\begin{eqnarray}
\left\vert \frac{2n^2}{5n^2+1}-\frac{2}{5}\right\vert&=&\frac{2}{25n^2+5}\\
&<&\frac{1}{n^2}\\
&<&\frac{1}{N^2}\\
&<&\epsilon
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Given the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2n^2}{5n^2+1}$ you have to group by $n^2$. It becomes:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2n^2}{5n^2+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n^2\cdot 2}{n^2\cdot\left(5+\frac 1{n^2}\right)}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2}{\left(5+\frac 1{n^2}\right)}=\dfrac 25$$

Because we know that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(5+\frac 1{n^2}\right)=5$

Comment: but I want to use the definition...

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\frac{2n^2}{5n^2+1} = \frac{2}{5} \frac{n^2}{n^2+\frac{1}{5}}$. Subtract $\frac{2}{5}$, and you get:
$\frac{2}{5} \left|\frac{n^2}{n^2+\frac{1}{5}}-1\right| = \frac{2}{5}\left|\frac{\frac{1}{5}}{n^2+\frac{1}{5}}\right|$.
Now we can always take $N>0$ such that for all $n>N$, this is smaller than $\epsilon$. Can you see why?

Answer (score 0):

$|{\frac{2}{5(5n^2+1)}}|<\frac{2}{25n^2}<\varepsilon$. So $n>\frac{\sqrt2}{5\sqrt\varepsilon}$ and $N=[{\frac{\sqrt2}{5\sqrt\varepsilon}}]+1$